# Difficulty in Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

I need to solve a logic problem using Prolog. I have just one problem:

In the answer, the name of the attributes doesn't appear. My code to generate the attributes is:

```
gera(p(Prof, AlunosProf, Tema, AlunosTema)) :-
       member(Prof, [palmira, roberta, selma]),
       member(AlunosProf, [40, 45, 50]),
       member(Tema, [transito, culinaria, reciclagem]);
       member(AlunosTema, [40, 45, 50]).
```

But after doing the query it looks like this:

```
S = [p(palmira, _G2046, transito, 45),
    p(roberta, 50, reciclagem, _G2053),
    p(selma, _G2056, culinaria, _G2058)]
```

Where is "_G***something**" I want to appear **the name of the attribute** (in this case only the number of students).

**Edit**:

Adding the entire code:

```
gera(p(Prof, AlunosProf, Tema, AlunosTema)) :-
       member(Prof, [palmira, roberta, selma]),
       member(AlunosProf, [40, 45, 50]),
       member(Tema, [transito, culinaria, reciclagem]),
       member(AlunosTema, [40, 45, 50]).


dif(p(P1, Q1, T1, Q12), p(P2, Q2, T2, Q22)) :-
    P1 \= P2, Q1 \= Q2, Q12 \= Q22, T1 \= T2.

tudoDif(P1, P2, P3) :-
    dif(P1, P2), dif(P1, P3), dif(P2, P3).

gera_ef(P1, P2, P3) :-
    P1 = p(palmira, _, _, _),
    P2 = p(roberta, _, _, _),
    P3 = p(selma, _, _, _).
    gera(P1), gera(P2), gera(P3),
    tudoDif(P1,P2,P3).

solucao(S) :-
        S = [P1, P2, P3],
    gera_ef(P1, P2, P3),
    member(p(palmira, X, transito, 45), S),
        member(p(selma, Z, culinaria, W), S),
        member(p(roberta, 50, reciclagem, R), S), 
    !.
```

Comment: Alguma ideia do que pode estar errado, mineiro ?

Comment: olha o edit no meu post; please, check the edit in my post

Comment: Valeu, cara. Me ajudaste bastante. Thank u buddy. U helped me so much.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please, mark it as the valid answer to your post by clicking on the tick mark, below the voting arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are relaxing the constraint of you statement when you use `;` instead of `,`.
When you use `;` you're stating that, either what came before **or** what is coming now is acceptable.

Since when you start saying "what is coming now" you only define the values of `AlunosTema`, the other values will receive *any* value, represented by what you saw -- "_G233...".

Try the following:

```
gera(p(Prof, AlunosProf, Tema, AlunosTema)) :-
       member(Prof, [palmira, roberta, selma]),
       member(AlunosProf, [40, 45, 50]),
       member(Tema, [transito, culinaria, reciclagem]),
       member(AlunosTema, [40, 45, 50]).
```

**Edit**:

Considering the whole code you posted, you may change some couple of things:

```
...

gera_ef(P1, P2, P3) :-
    P1 = p(palmira, _, _, _),
    P2 = p(roberta, _, _, _),
    P3 = p(selma, _, _, _),
    gera(P1),
    gera(P2),
    gera(P3),
    tudoDif(P1,P2,P3).

solucao(S) :-
    S = [P1, P2, P3],
    gera_ef(P1, P2, P3),
    member(p(palmira, _, transito, 45), S),
    member(p(selma, _, culinaria, _), S),
    member(p(roberta, 50, reciclagem, _), S),
    !.
```

The problem here is that you had a `.` instead of a `,` in:

```
gera_ef(P1, P2, P3) :-
    ...,
    P3 = p(selma, _, _, _).
    ...
```

that wouldn't allow the rest of the code to execute.

Another change was the replacement of the unbounded variables in `solucao` with `_`; note `X, W, R` have been removed.

Comment: Aqui funcionou perfeitamente, cara, dá uma olhada em como você está fazendo a busca; tenta executar algo como: `gera(X).`, e vai pressionando `;` pra ver os resultados.
It worked fine here; try to run the query as `gera(X).`, and press `;` to get each result.

Comment: Sim, quando executo o gera(X) funciona, mas qdo executo o método solucao(S) aparece o que disse antes.

Comment: Você não postou nada sobre método `solucao(S)` aqui, cara, fica difícil ajudar assim. You did not post any `solucao(S)` method, so there's no way to no what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code. You put a colon where you meant a comma:

The line

```
member(Tema, [transito, culinaria, reciclagem]);
```

should read

```
member(Tema, [transito, culinaria, reciclagem]),
```